# Liquibase schema-qualified change log

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

Is it possible and what are best practices for generating schema-qualified object names in a Liquibase change log .sql file?

For example, I want the command `liquibase generateChangeLog` to generate a .sql file where the objects are schema qualified (`CREATE TABLE [schema_name].[table_name]...`).  What I get is something like `CREATE TABLE [table_name]...` without the schema qualification.

I have tried the schemas and defaultSchema properties and their command-line equivalent w/no success.  I have also tried setting the default schema for the liquibase login w/no success.

P.S. - this is for an MSSQL database.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using --includeSchema or --includeCatalog optional arguments with liquibaseGenerateChangeLog command?

Here's the [documentation](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/generatechangelog.html) that mentions these optional arguments:

Comment: Yes.  Unfortunately those flags don't seem to have any effect on the output.